# CountDownLatch in C++ using Boost Mutexes and Condition

Tags: c++, unit-testing, countdownlatch

I tried to implement CountDownLatch using boost mutexes and condition variable. Below is the code and would like to know if I need to add anything else.

How can I unit test this code as well?

```
template< class TypeVal >
    class AtomicCounter
    {
    public:
        AtomicCounter( TypeVal val ) : m_typeVal( val ) 
        {
        }

        AtomicCounter() : m_typeVal(0)
        {
        }

        AtomicCounter(const AtomicCounter& cpy) : m_typeVal(cpy.m_typeVal)
        {   
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock scoped_lock(cpy.m_atomicMutex);
            m_typeVal = cpy.m_typeVal;
        }

        const AtomicCounter& operator=(const AtomicCounter& other)
        {
           if (this == &other)
              return *this;
           boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock1(&m_atomicMutex < &other.m_atomicMutex ? m_atomicMutex : other.m_atomicMutex);
           boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock2(&m_atomicMutex > &other.m_atomicMutex ? m_atomicMutex : other.m_atomicMutex);
           m_typeVal = other.m_typeVal;
           return *this;
        }

        virtual ~AtomicCounter() 
        {
        }

        const TypeVal& getCount() const
        { 
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( m_atomicMutex ); 
            return m_typeVal; 
        }

        const TypeVal& setCount( const TypeVal &val ) 
        { 
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( m_atomicMutex ); 
            m_typeVal = val; 
            return m_typeVal; 
        }

        const TypeVal& increment() 
        { 
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( m_atomicMutex ); 
            m_typeVal++ ; 
            return m_typeVal; 
        }

        const TypeVal& decrement() 
        { 
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( m_atomicMutex ); 
            m_typeVal-- ; 
            return m_typeVal; 
        }

        const TypeVal& increment(const TypeVal& t) 
        { 
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( m_atomicMutex ); 
            m_typeVal+=t ; 
            return m_typeVal; 
        }

        const TypeVal& decrement(const TypeVal& t) 
        { 
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( m_atomicMutex ); 
            m_typeVal-=t ; 
            return m_typeVal; 
        }


    private:
        mutable boost::mutex m_atomicMutex;
        TypeVal m_typeVal;
    };

           class CountDownLatch
    {
    public:
        CountDownLatch( int count ): m_cdlCount( count ) 
        {
        }

        CountDownLatch(const CountDownLatch& cpy)
        {
             boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>::unique_lock(const_cast<boost::mutex&>(cpy.m_cdlMutex));
            m_cdlCount = cpy.m_cdlCount;
        }

        const CountDownLatch& operator=(const CountDownLatch& other)
        {
           if (this == &other)
              return *this;
           boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock1(const_cast<boost::mutex&>(&m_cdlMutex < &other.m_cdlMutex ? m_cdlMutex : other.m_cdlMutex));
           boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock2(const_cast<boost::mutex&>(&m_cdlMutex > &other.m_cdlMutex ? m_cdlMutex : other.m_cdlMutex));
           m_cdlCount = other.m_cdlCount;
           return *this;
        }

        virtual ~CountDownLatch() 
        {
        }
        void wait() 
        { 
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( m_cdlMutex ); 
            if( m_cdlCount.getCount() > 0 ) 
            { 
                m_cdlCondition.wait( lock ); 
            } 
        }
        void wait( uint64_t timeoutMicros ) 
        { 
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( m_cdlMutex ); 
            if( m_cdlCount.getCount() > 0 ) 
            {
                boost::posix_time::time_duration td = boost::posix_time::milliseconds( timeoutMicros ); 
                m_cdlCondition.timed_wait( lock, td ); 
            } 
        }
        void countDown() 
        {  
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( m_cdlMutex ); 
            if( m_cdlCount.decrement() == 0 ) 
            { 
                m_cdlCondition.notify_all(); 
            } 
        }

        int getCount()
        {
            return m_cdlCount.getCount();
        }


    private:
        boost::mutex m_cdlMutex;
        boost::condition_variable m_cdlCondition;
        AtomicCounter< int >  m_cdlCount;           
    };
```

Comment: The code is flawed. Take for example the method AtomicCounter::getCount, you are returning by reference a member that is supposed to be changed by another thread (why use the locks otherwise?) You need to return the counter in that method by copy. Some other methods are affected by the same design flaw. Also why are you using (wasting resources) post increments when what you need is a preincrement ?

Comment: FYI [boost's latch class (experimental, v1.67)](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.latches)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unit testing, you can try stress-testing. For example, for CountDownLatch, create 25 test threads that simultaneously call `CountDownLatch::countDown()`, 25 other threads that simultaneously call `CountDownLatch::getCount()`, and 25 others threads that call `CountDownLatch::wait()`. To make things more simultaneous, use a barrier, or make the threads sleep until the same absolute time. Make sure that all threads terminate properly (no deadlocks) by joining all of them. Make sure that `CountDownLatch::m_cdlCount` ends up at zero.

Run the same test many times (for a reasonable amount of time).

You can use the same basic idea for AtomicCounter.

There are probably other techniques for testing multitheaded code, but this is the one I'm most familiar with.